# How can by macro as parameter of other macro?

Tags: macros, xstring

`\StrPosition{AQ2 K863 1065 J1065}{ }` give **4** 
`\StrMid{AQ2 K863 1065 J1065}{1}{4}` give **AQ2**

`\StrMid{AQ2 K863 1065 J1065}{1}{\StrPosition{AQ2 K863 1065 J1065}{ } }` i want **AQ2**
but give error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nesting macros of the `xstring` package is not possible; you can use the optional argument in last position. The syntax is `[<name>]`, where `<name>` is the name of the control sequence that will receive the result of the macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

\StrPosition{AQ2 K863 1065 J1065}{ }[\myname]
\StrMid{AQ2 K863 1065 J1065}{1}{4}

\StrMid{AQ2 K863 1065 J1065}{1}{\myname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Under TeXwork on my NB itis work. But under QuickLaTeX on my Wordpress page write error Not allowed command sequence.

Comment: @TiborMenyhért this should work nicely with [QuickLaTeX](http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/quicklatex/). Did you add `xstring` to the preamble?: `[latex][+preamble]\usepackage{xstring}[/preamble] ... [/latex]`